# Elegant solution to place a circuit element in middle of path in circuitikz/tikz

Tags: circuitikz

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[betterproportions]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw
node[op amp](opamp){}
(opamp.out) to [short,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(out)

%some opamp ``breakout''
(opamp.+) -| ++(-0.5,-1) node[rground]{}
(opamp.-)  to [short] ++(-2, 0)  node[open]{in} coordinate(in)

%feedback resistor
($ (in) !.5! (out) $) coordinate(xFB) node[open]{} %helper to get midpoint of in to out
(xFB |- 0,3)  coordinate(RFB) %orthogonal coordinate to construct a (x,y) above the opamp

%want to have R_FB in the middle, in pseudo code something like:
% Pseudo code that would be nice (in) |- R at (RFB) -| (out)

(in) |- (RFB) to [R, l=$R_{FB}$] ++(2,0) -| (out) 

;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

What is an elegant solution of placing the feedback resistor nicely in the middle between (in) and (out) concerning the x-coordinate?. I have the coordinate of the middle already calculated but how to place the middle (and not the starting point) of the resistor there?

I came up with some workarounds by splitting the path into 4 (sub-) paths but that does not seem very elegeant and I assume there is a more elegant way to do that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question, but: the basic idea is that when you use `(A) to[R] (B)` the component is placed in the middle of `(A)--(B)`. Always (the problem is getting a different position).

Comment: Hmm, so when I want to make use of orthogonal coordinates, I have to draw to separate paths (input to just a little bit left before the middle point + output to just a little bit right before the middle point) and then fit the resistor into a straight path between those two paths? That seems a bit cumbersome because i have to calculate those coordinates "just a bit left/right" to the middle. Not sure whether the question became clearer :P

Comment: @Junius see my answer here, feel free to ask in comment there if it is not exactly what you want. Anyway, if you want an element "around" a coordinate you can always use `([xshift=-1cm]C) to[R] ([xshift=1cm]C)` although it's ugly like hell...

Comment: @Julius I added the general way to "put the component EXACTLY HERE" question --- I hope that one of the solutions provided works for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic idea in `circuitikz`  is that when you use `(A) to[R] (B)` the component is placed in the middle of `(A)--(B)`. Always... the problem is getting a different position.

So I propose a couple of solutions here --- I have heavily commented the code. Notice that the open pole is called `ocirc`, not `open` (that one is a fake, "nothing"-shape for the *open circuit* "component").

```latex
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[betterproportions]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw
node[op amp](opamp){}
(opamp.out) to [short,-*] ++(2,0) coordinate(out)

%some opamp ``breakout''
(opamp.+) -| ++(-0.5,-1) node[rground]{}
(opamp.-)  to [short] ++(-2, 0)  node[ocirc]{} coordinate(in) node[left]{in}

%feedback resistor
%notice that this is not where you think it is, probably...
% I added colors to show where you are, but you do not need any of this.
($ (in) !.5! (out) $) coordinate(xFB) node[color=red, ocirc]{} %helper to get midpoint of in to out

(xFB |- 0,3) node[color=green, ocirc]{} coordinate(RFB) %orthogonal coordinate to construct a (x,y) above the opamp

% when using to[], the element is positioned in the middle
([yshift=3cm]in) to[R] ([yshift=3cm]in-|out)

% I find this more elegant though, but it's a matter of taste; you have just
% one number to change if you want to shift it
(in) ++(0,2) coordinate(tmp) to[L] (tmp-|out)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to position the resistor manually, you can do it. For example, let's suppose you want to position the resistor above the center of the amplifier, independently from the position of the lead wires. What you can do is to use the "shape-name" for the resistor (you find it in the manual for every path-style component) and then you connect the wires yourself. Notice that this way you have to take care of the rotation, if any, and that the `label`, `annotation`, `v`, and other decorations will not work.

```latex
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw
node[op amp](opamp){}
(opamp.out) -- ++(0.5,0) coordinate(out+)
            to [short,-*] ++(2,0) node[right]{out}
(opamp.+) -| ++(-0.5,-1) node[rground](GND){}
(opamp.-)  to [short,-o] ++(-2, 0) coordinate(in) node[left]{in}
% find the position where I want the resistor to be
(opamp.center) ++(0,2)
% and position the node-style shape
node[resistorshape](RF){}
% now connect it
(GND|-in) |- (RF.left) (RF.right) -| (opamp.out)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Anyway, I would draw this like:

```latex
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[line width=1pt]
\draw
node[op amp](opamp){}
(opamp.out) -- ++(0.5,0) coordinate(out+)
            to [short,-*] ++(2,0) node[right]{out}
(opamp.+) -| ++(-0.5,-1) node[rground](GND){}
(opamp.-)  to [short,-o] ++(-2, 0) coordinate(in) node[left]{in}
(in-|GND) -- ++(0,2) coordinate(tmp) to[R] (tmp-|out+) -- (out+)
;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the excellent explanation as usual